# Messages are not moving to the folder in JavaMail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I´m trying to move a array of messages in my application.

But it doesn´t move any messages to folder.

I check with `folder` methods if `isOpen` or `exists` and is true for both methods.

If i create the folder using the inbox. I got inbox\foldername.

But I want to create foldername and move.

So whats wrong?

My folder are create by the `sender` name. I´m using `Gmail`.

```
for (Entry<String, List<Message>> senderAndMessages: mapMessagesBySender.entrySet()) {

    Message []arrayMessages = new Message[senderAndMessages.getValue().size()];
    arrayMessages = senderAndMessages.getValue().toArray(arrayMessages);
    Folder folder = store.getFolder(senderAndMessages.getKey());
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    folder.copyMessages(arrayMessages, folder);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the messages in to the same folder they're already in.  The Folder parameter is the destination folder, you need a second Folder object.

And I can't tell how you're getting the Message objects from the source folder, so you may be doing something wrong there as well.

Note that the destination folder does not need to be open.

Comment: ok, but when I use methods to ask if the folder exist, it return true.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the source folder exists, since you're reading messages from it.  The problem is that you haven't specified a destination folder.  Or rather, you have, but it's the same as the source folder.

Comment: I´m confuse, because when I make this command `Folder folder = store.getFolder(senderAndMessages.getKey());`, got the folder destionation. So I move to them...Could show me what would be the correct way?

My arraylist of messages are located in the inbox folder.

Comment: Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX"); Folder saved = store.getFolder("saved"); Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages(); inbox.copyMessages(msgs, saved);

Comment: I didn´t show all code, but in the begining of my code I got the inbox folder. `   Folder inbox = null;
   
   inbox = store.getDefaultFolder();
   inbox = inbox.getFolder("INBOX");
   inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);`

Comment: If you're not showing the code you're actually using, I can't tell what are mistakes in your real code and what are mistakes in your editing of the code for posting.  Also, the first three statements in your code above can be replaced by one statement: Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");